# Can find take a file as argument from stdin?

Tags: bash

I have a list of 3,900 ID numbers and I need to find on our FTP server the matching files.

Finding one file is quite simple e.g.

`find . -name "*IDNumber*" -exec ls '{}' ';' -print`

but how do I do this for 3,900 IDs numbers?  I created a file with the IDs like so

```
028892663163
028923481973
...
```

but how do I pass the list of ID numbers as argument? Can you provide some pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: How many total files in the file system? Might be faster to list them all and then grep the list.

Comment: Close to one million. The FTP server is a mass filer device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to reduce the number of times you have to invoke `find`:

```
find . -type f -print | grep -f id.file | xargs cp -t target_dir
```

Comment: @tripleee, you posted your comment while I was composing this answer ;)

Comment: Brilliant minds ... +1 for `cp -t`, didn't remember there was an option for that.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to optimize it by running find with more than one id at a time.

With *bash* (100 at a time, you may try with more):

```
c= p=
while IFS= read -r; do
  p+=" -name '*$REPLY*' -o " 
  (( ++c )) 
  (( c % 100 )) || {
    eval find .  ${p% -o } 
    p=
    }
done < id_list_all

[[ $p ]] && 
    eval find .  ${p% -o }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

- put all my 3,900 ID numbers in a file `outfile`
- typed the command line:

`cat outfile | while read line
do
    find . -name "$line" -exec cp '{}' /target_directory ';' -print
done`

Worked awesome!

Comment: Useless Use of Cat. Also probably more efficient to only run one find, as hinted in another comment; `find . -type f -print | fgrep -f outfile | xargs -i cp {} /target_directory`

Answer (score 0):

I read your question wrong the first time... arguments from find to other things. What you want is arguments from a file passed to find. So, here's the correct answer with [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs):

```
xargs --max-args=1 -I X -d '\n' find . -name X -exec [...] < your_list
```